# The SELECT statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that is misspelled or missing, or the punctuation is incorrect in access

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

The below code is suddenly deleted from Access randomly, i cant quite figure out what the problem might be. as you can see i am tring to do a simple query in an access database to produce a simple exported excel file.

```
SELECT 
    Tracking.Agency, 
    Tracking.[Vehicle Plate Number], 
    Villages.Mohafaza_LAF, 
    [ISC main table].[Mission to], 
    Tracking.Purpose, 
    Tracking.Driver, 
    Tracking.[Driver Phone Number], 
    [Passanger 1] & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & [Passanger 2] & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & [Passanger 3] & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & [Passanger 4] & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & [Passanger 5] AS Passengers
FROM 
    Villages 
    INNER JOIN (
        Villages_Query 
        INNER JOIN (
            [ISC main table] 
            INNER JOIN Tracking ON [ISC main table].ID = Tracking.[Mission ID]
        ) ON (Villages_Query.Villages = Tracking.To) AND (Villages_Query.Villages = [ISC main table].[Mission to])
    ) ON (Villages.Villages = Tracking.To) AND (Villages.Villages = Villages_Query.Villages) AND (Villages.Villages = [ISC main table].[Mission to])
WHERE 
    (
        (
            (Villages_Query.Zones)="Red" 
            Or (Villages_Query.Zones)="Red Dotted" 
            Or (Villages_Query.Zones)="Yellow" 
            Or (Villages_Query.Zones)="Yellow Dotted" 
            Or (Villages_Query.Zones)="Red Shaded"
        ) 
        AND (Tracking.[Mission Date] = [Forms]![LAF_Date]![Report_Date]) 
        AND ([ISC main table].[ISC initial status]="Written")
    ) 
    OR 
    (
        (Tracking.[Mission Date] = [Forms]![LAF_Date]![Report_Date]) 
        AND ([ISC main table].LAFFF="-1")
    )
ORDER BY 
    Villages.Mohafaza_LAF, Villages_Query.Zones;
```

well this is my 1st try

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide-and-conquer_algorithm

Comment: you really should avoid spaces in column names

Comment: thanks but still no luck, same issue, code suddenly disappears and i have to paste it again in the query tab

Comment: Maybe `Date` from [Mission Date] causes the issue - add an underscore like with the other date columns. Maybe same with `table`

Comment: Maybe "Passanger" should be "Passenger". We can't really tell. Carefully compare the names with the table and query definitions. You could simplify the query with `Villages_Query.Zones IN ("Red", "Red Dotted", "Yellow", "Yellow Dotted", "Red Shaded")`.

Comment: Is LAFFF a yes/no data type? If so, don't put -1 within quotes. Multiple similar name fields (Passanger1, Passanger2, etc.) indicates a non-normalized schema. Although fields might have those names, Passanger is a misspelling.

Comment: well thanks for the response guys although i tried all of the above an changed the entire parameter names it still deletes the code randomly.

Comment: If the code is being "deleted" randomly then the Access database may be corrupt, this happens sometimes and the fix is to stop using the database immediately, save your code and DDL as text files and create a new database. You may need to reinstall Access. Try [this](https://davetallett26.github.io/makeddl.html) but copy your database first!

Comment: Well apparently it was corrupted after all. So i had to start from scratch and it worked like charm. ‍♂️ thanks for the feedback guys.